# Javascript simple 'animation' issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to replicate this webpage for training purposes:
http://demo.themeum.com/html/triangle/1.1/
Working on menu I've encountered following problem: after clicking on magnifying-glass icon my input field doesn't appear, why ?

```
 <div class="row-second">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="C:\Users\zebru\Desktop\triangle\trg_logo.png" id="logo">
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="navb" id="navbb">
            <a href="#" class="nav-title">HOME  <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <a href="#">Single Color</a>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav-title">PAGES  <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">About2</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">Pricing</a>
            </div>

          <a href="#"class="nav-title">BLOG  <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <a href="#">Blog Default</a>
                <a href="#">Timeline Blog</a>
                <a href="#">1Column + Left Sidebar</a>
                <a href="#">Blog Masonary</a>
                <a href="#">Blog Details</a>
            </div>

           <a href="#"class="nav-title">PORTFOLIO  <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div class="nav-content">
                <a href="#">Portfolio Default</a>
                <a href="#">Isotope 3Columns + Right Sidebar</a>
                <a href="#">1Column + Left Sidebar</a>
                <a href="#">3Columns + Right Sidebar</a>
                <a href="#">Portfolio Details</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="nav-title">SHORTCODES</a>
            <span class="fa fa-search fa-fw nav-title" id="mag" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.fortext_instyle{   
    border:2px solid rgb(68, 204, 219);
    border-radius:6px;
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("mag").addEventListener("click", function(){

 var newelement=document.createElement("input");
 newelement.className="fortext_instyle";
 document.getElementById("navbb").appendChild(newelement);

});



 Full CSS:


 div .col-md-3 {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

    .row-first {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    .social-icons .fa-ul {
        color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-right: -300px;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .social-icons .fa-ul:last-child {
        padding-right: 0px;
    }

    .social-icons ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0 7px;
    }

    .navb {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .nav-title {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #575757;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-right: 25px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }



    .nav-content {
        display: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .nav-content a {
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: dimgray;
        display: block;
        text-align: justify;
        line-height: 200%
    }

    .nav-title:hover {
        color: rgb(0, 153, 170);
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    .nav-content a:focus{

        background-color: rgb(68, 204, 219);

    }

.nav-title:hover + .nav-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 0.25px solid rgb(68, 204, 219);
}



.nav-title:last-child{

    color:rgb(68, 204, 219);

}




.fa-ul li:hover{
    color: rgb(68, 204, 219);
}

.fa-ul li:nth-child(4):hover{
    color: #c7445f;
}

.fa-ul li:nth-child(3):hover{
    color: #670909;
}

.fortext_instyle{

    border:2px solid rgb(68, 204, 219);
    border-radius:6px;

}
```

Comment: works fine https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/MoawpE

Comment: It would be useful to see more of the CSS that you're using, as this is likely the problem area. The JS works as expected and appends an input, though there is no logic to remove that input again.

Comment: Thanks for remarks @Jesse. I've checked on Codepen and It really seems to work but I'm still confused why It doesn't work on my environment. I'm adding my full css.